# Wordpress вставить шорткод в php

Tags: php, wordpress, shortcode, шорткод

Не судите строго, но далек от php.
Нужно вставить шорткод

`<?php echo do_shortcode( '[POST_MODIFIED]' ); ?>`

Вставить в последнюю строку, где "Обновлено" не получается

```
    <?php if ( $is_show_meta ) { ?>
    <div class="entry-meta">
        <?php if ( $is_show_author ) echo '<span class="entry-author" itemprop="author"><span class="entry-label">' . __( 'Author', THEME_TEXTDOMAIN ) . '</span> ' . get_the_author() . '</span>'; ?>
        <?php if ( $is_show_reading_time ) echo '<span class="entry-time"><span class="entry-label">' . __( 'Reading', THEME_TEXTDOMAIN ) . '</span> ' . wpshop_read_time() . ' ' . __( 'min', THEME_TEXTDOMAIN ) . '</span>'; ?>
        <?php if ( $is_show_views && $wpshop_template->get_views() > 0 ) {
            echo '<span class="entry-views"><span class="entry-label">' . __( 'Views', THEME_TEXTDOMAIN ) . '</span> ' . $wpshop_helper->rounded_number( $wpshop_template->get_views() ) . '</span>';
        } ?>
        <?php if ( $is_show_date ) echo '<span class="entry-date"><span class="entry-label">' . __( 'Published by', THEME_TEXTDOMAIN ) . '</span> <time itemprop="datePublished" datetime="' . get_the_time('Y-m-d') . '">' . get_the_date() . '</time></span>'; ?>
        <?php if ( $is_show_date ) echo '<span class="entry-date"><span class="entry-label">' . __( 'Обновлено', THEME_TEXTDOMAIN ) . '</span> <time itemprop="dateModified" datetime="' . get_the_time('Y-m-d') . '">' . get_the_date() . '</time></span>'; ?>
    </div>
<?php } ?>
```

Все добра и спасибо)

Comment: Так а в чем проблема? Что конкретно не получается? Куда конкретно вы хотите вставить шорткод? Что это за шорткод?

Comment: В нижнюю строку <?php if ( $is_show_date )
Не пойму как на php грамотно вставить, чтобы сохранить все остальное))

Comment: Дополните вопрос, покажите, как вы вставляли шорткод. Мне просто непонятно, какие с этим сложности могут возникнуть

Comment: Как то так пытаюсь впихнуть))
<?php if ( $is_show_date ) echo '<span class="entry-date"><span class="entry-label">' . __( 'Обновлено', THEME_TEXTDOMAIN ) . '</span> <time itemprop="dateModified" datetime="'[POST_MODIFIED]'"></time></span>'; ?>

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Все шорткоды, которые выполняет WP, выполняются через `do_shortcode()`, поэтому шорткод нужно вызывать через эту функцию: `do_shortcode('[POST_MODIFIED]')`

Вдобавок ко всему, строки сами себя не соединят, конкатенация в php делается через оператор `.`.

А дальше только все это соединить:

```
<?php if ( $is_show_meta ) { ?>
    <div class="entry-meta">
        <?php if ( $is_show_author ) echo '<span class="entry-author" itemprop="author"><span class="entry-label">' . __( 'Author', THEME_TEXTDOMAIN ) . '</span> ' . get_the_author() . '</span>'; ?>
        <?php if ( $is_show_reading_time ) echo '<span class="entry-time"><span class="entry-label">' . __( 'Reading', THEME_TEXTDOMAIN ) . '</span> ' . wpshop_read_time() . ' ' . __( 'min', THEME_TEXTDOMAIN ) . '</span>'; ?>
        <?php if ( $is_show_views && $wpshop_template->get_views() > 0 ) {
            echo '<span class="entry-views"><span class="entry-label">' . __( 'Views', THEME_TEXTDOMAIN ) . '</span> ' . $wpshop_helper->rounded_number( $wpshop_template->get_views() ) . '</span>';
        } ?>
        <?php if ( $is_show_date ) echo '<span class="entry-date"><span class="entry-label">' . __( 'Published by', THEME_TEXTDOMAIN ) . '</span> <time itemprop="datePublished" datetime="' . get_the_time('Y-m-d') . '">' . get_the_date() . '</time></span>'; ?>
        <?php if ( $is_show_date ) echo '<span class="entry-date"><span class="entry-label">' . __( 'Обновлено', THEME_TEXTDOMAIN ) . '</span> <time itemprop="dateModified" datetime="' . do_shortcode('[POST_MODIFIED]') . '"></time></span>'; ?>
    </div>
<?php } ?>
```